# Launch ELK services using python script

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am writing a script in python which starts an elasticsearch, kibana server at localhost 9200. All examples I found on the internet are regarding connectivity to an existing elasticsearch instance running at localhost 9200.
My moto is that I want to have a script by which I can start and stop the ELK server in one go without going to use the command line to start or stop the server.

Basically, the task is replace this line

```
bin/elasticsearch
```

with something in python.

I have tried the following

```
subprocess.Popen(path + '/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-'+version+'/bin/elasticsearch')
subprocess.Popen(path + '/kibana/kibana-'+version+'-darwin-x86_64/bin/kibana')
```

However, I am not able to start the services with this code. For first time it got started but for killing the running process I need to find the PID pf process and kill it manually by using,

```
kill <PID>
```

But when I try to restart the services it tells an instance already created for the services and it starts elasticsearch service on another port localhost:9201 and kibana fails to start due to elasticsearch conflict.

Suggest some ways to start and stop the services to achieve the task required.

Could anyone provide a code snippet of how I would go about creating the elasticsearch, kibana servers instance programmatically/automatically? Are there any existing projects that do this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: it's not clear why you want to do this when things like systemd exist?

Comment: each time it needed to start multiple resources before using elk so want to create a way such that running only one file all services starts.

Comment: docker would be better if you could use that?

Comment: yeah sure I found how to get it executed through docker and that's useful.